# Typescript: only name/destructure optional properties when taking an interface parameter?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to typescript and am writing some classes to work as a very simple ORM for my project. I just learned how to require that a parameter conform to an interface, like so:

```
interface UserInfo {
    userId: string
    email?: string
    // many more properties...
}
class User {
    constructor(connection: typeof db, init: UserInfo) {
    // code here
```

And I understand that the syntax to set default values for those optional properties is:

```
class User {
    constructor(connection: typeof db, {email = null, /*...*/}: UserInfo) {
    // code here
```

But my `UserInfo` interface is long, what if I want to only specify/default a few of the properties, without typing out a giant object in the parameters for the constructor of this object? Is there a way to require an entire interface, but destructure only some properties?

Comment: What's `typeof db`?  And `null` isn't a `string | undefined`.  Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mbGgbW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  There should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Also I think I'm confused... if you destructure just some of the properties, you're throwing the other ones away and not using them.  Maybe don't destructure at all and just use object spread instead inside the function?  The example code we need here should involve doing something with the constructor implementation.  And maybe call the constructor too.  I can't tell if your optional properties are meant to be optional from the call side or in the implementation side.

Comment: @jcalz You can just ignore the code I included, I'm just asking if it's possible to take an entire object that conforms to an interface as a parameter, but only destructure one or two properties of the object in order to set default values

Edit: Ok I think your second post answered my question, I will just not destructure it, take the entire object as a parameter, and set default values inside the constructor if the property does not exist

Comment: I mean, if you provide a [mre] then I'm more inclined to work on it.  Otherwise maybe someone else will come along who doesn't need an example.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAv4XW) meet your needs? If so I could maybe write an answer.

Comment: Ooh yes that's perfect! Thank you very much

Comment: @the_midnight_developer Remember that destructuring is just a syntactic construct intended to make some things easier. If it leads to a more cumbersome code, it would probably be a better idea to defer to less exotic constructs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) isn't really a great fit, because that essentially ignores any properties you don't explicitly mention. In order not to lose track of the unmentioned properties, you could destructure into a *rest* object:

```
class User {
  constructor({ email = "xyz", ...rest }: UserInfo) {}
}
```

But now you have a variable named `email` with a `string` value in it which is either the one passed in or the default `"xyz"` (not `null`, by the way; `null` is not a `string`) if none was passed in.  And you also have a variable named `rest` with an `Omit<UserInfo, "email">` value in it (I'm using [the `Omit<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) to represent what happens when you widen a type to forget about some property keys).

If you actually need a value of type `Required<UserInfo>` (I'm using [the `Required<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) to represent a type with any optional properties changed to be required), then you'll need to reassemble it from those pieces, such as via shorthand property names in your [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) along with [object spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
class User {
  userInfo: Required<UserInfo>
  constructor({ email = "xyz", ...rest }: UserInfo) { // <-- split it apart       
    this.userInfo = { email, ...rest }; // <-- put it back together
  }
}
```

That works, but it is needlessly destructive (if you'll forgive the pun).

---

Instead, you can just use spreading to get more or less the same effect:

```
class User {
  userInfo: Required<UserInfo>
  constructor(init: UserInfo) {
    this.userInfo = { email: "xyz", ...init };
  }
}
```

If the passed-in constructor argument has no `email` property, then the default one of `"xyz"` will be there.  Otherwise the argument's `email` property will overwrite the default.

---

Anyway in both cases you can see that it works as desired:

```
const u = new User({ userId: "abc" });
console.log(u.userInfo.userId) // abc
console.log(u.userInfo.email) // xyz

const v = new User({ userId: "def", email: "ghi" });
console.log(v.userInfo.userId) // def
console.log(v.userInfo.email) // ghi
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.5.4&ssl=26&ssc=11&pln=26&pc=24#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdoEkQwPbIDeAUMsgK6ZRYAmAXMumFKAOanIQC2cwANgH4GTFiHZkA9BOQ8QATxl4oKAA5Q8K6GGAR0AOgPEAvsVMg4XXSsQoAIrubkEYcsqIcEfOOnRoq7sjJKbFw8BgAlCABHcmBlGgAeDBD8AD4OMgQ8EBEnMCUACkJOHn5kAF5kACIADzkALyqAGmQDPWUmZCMGZOpQgEoAwLIwAAtgfWC+-AqiEt4+FraOsC6AbgyujhMPbM7yWZAIAHc-aCKKKloGKrgAIwQqrv6NzL28Pgg9PjxWAvI9FMcPhAVcaIMpMh7ghdjkPl8fn8AUDQnpuAsIdI6vVTG8cqsAG6HE5nKAXIH0ao0CAwZrzfg3VjjJ5GF6w9Dw76-AoE0EpPB86jg5CQ6kwdmcxE8wXAgXo-iY5BM4CmHbmSzoaxIZAAZTUEDgNBwTANNCGnm8vl6QyCV1CEWisXiSTtaU2WXxUDyhVAwDAPVdeEGJGGI3Gk0Ds2K8r4N2xdLavtWRlegRMZB2eP2xNOvXJYJu0JZbKzku5yMDMuFkOhEs+XKRMtRMcV2NxyA9nSJlSOuao+ewlKqYrpMcZzOeqc7Zb+vJRIIpirFdYR3LnlZbIukyuMxCAA)

Comment: "`null` is not a `string`" -- actually, it is if `strictNullCheck` is `false`, which it is by default

Comment: I didn't want to digress too much talking about `--strictNullChecks`, but sure.  Although if you set a value of type `string` to `null` on purpose, you're setting yourself up for a bad time... even in JavaScript's relatively weak type system, `null` is not a `string`.  The compiler option defaults are the way they are for backwards compatibility, and not because they're "good" options per se (see [this issue comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24773#issuecomment-395797268)).